# Relationship between TypeScript and ES6

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6

All:

I am pretty new to Typescript and ES6, the first thing confuses me is their relationship, from MSDN:

> TypeScript 1.5 adds a number of new ES6 features including modules,
>   destructuring, spread, for..of, symbols, computed properties,
>   let/const, and tagged string templates.

My confuse is(I know there are  lots of posts say that the Typescript is the superset of JS):

**Dose this mean TypeScript just use its own way( some slightly diff syntax and transpile) to redo what already exists in ES6 again( just for type purpose ),**

and

**Does it mean ES6 basically can do everything that in TypeScript? and vice versa**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

TypeScript is a script code that is transpiled to JavaScript - either to ES5 or ES6 (and ES3 too).

> TypeScript 1.5 adds a number of new ES6 features including modules,
>   destructuring, spread, for..of, symbols, computed properties,
>   let/const, and tagged string templates.

This means that you can use modules, for..of and other features in your TypeScript code and TypeScript compiler transpiles your code to ESx compatible code that does the same thing. Let's take `for..of` for instance:

TypeScript code:

```
for (let t of [1,2,3]) {
    console.log(t)
}
```

is transpiled to ES5 like this:

```
for (var _i = 0, _a = [1, 2, 3]; _i < _a.length; _i++) {
    var t = _a[_i];
    console.log(t);
}
```

However, if you target ES6, then the transpilation is simply:

```
for (let t of [1,2,3]) {
    console.log(t);
}
```

The same holds for modules, spread, etc. In each case TypeScript generates code that behaves the same in ES5, ES6 and ES6 (it's simplified because it's not always possible).

There is not difference in expressivity of TypeScript and ES6. The difference is that TypeScript compiler helps you with static analysis of your code. Otherwise, whatever you can program in ES6, you can program in TypeScript and the other way around.

Comment: The reason I ask this is when I firstly study Angular2, in the quick start section, even it says "Angular2 for typescript", the code still include ES6 code like import from, so I just wondering if typescript can do everything in ES6 or I still need to know ES6 in order to use angular 2

Comment: Well, I think the answer is "it depends". ES6 functions like Object.assign are the same in both languages. Modules in TypeScript should behave very similarly to those in ES6 and TypeScript tries its best to align with ES6 features. So you won't have to learn two completely different languages.

Comment: Thanks, I guess it is the similarity bring the confuse to me.

Comment: TypeScript has additional features that EcmaScript doesn't have (yet, at least)

Comment: @vkurchatkin Yes. I just tried to keep my answers short. There is a myriad of details but it might scare people. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Typescript is a compiler that creates ecmascript. The Typescript source is code that has support for types, interfaces, super/subclasses and whatever you know from other programming languages. As mentioned, the result is ecmascript, that runs in any browser.

Comment: Thanks, does that mean I do not need to know any ES6 as long as I can use typescript? The reason I ask this is when I firstly study Angular2, in the quick start section, even it says "Angular2 for typescript", the code still include ES6 code like import from, so I just wondering if typescript can do everything in ES6 or I still need to know ES6 in order to use angular 2

Answer (score 2):

ecmascript is a standard specification of which Javascript follows.  ES5, ES6, ES7 are versions of this standard specification.  Typescript is complied down into Javascript.  Depending on the version of node compiler that you have will determine which version of Javascript standard version your Typescript will be compiled to.